# Defining a set of PDE equations || Reaction Diffusion Equation

Tags: julia, differential-equations

I am trying to solve a set of reaction-diffusion equation in 1-D using NeuralPDE. But I am facing difficulty in defining the set of equations. I want to define two PDEs. One force balance equation and other reaction-diffusion. With 't' as independent variable and xc(pos of cm) and u(conc) as dependent variable, I want to define two Neumann BC, three IC.
[Governing Equations, IC and BC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FeQ5s.png)

```
@parameters x, t
@variables xc(..), u(..)
Dx = Differential(x);
Dt = Differential(t);
Dxx = Differential(x)^2
Dtt = Differential(t)^2

gamma_0 = 1; c = 1; ρ = 1; μ = 1; D_coef = 1; k = 1; ro = 1;b = 1.0; S0 = 1;
L = 10.0; x0 = L/2;

F_func(x, xc, ro) = abs(xc - x) >= r0 ? S0 : 0;

# γ = gamma_0/(c*u + 1)
force_eq = ρ*Dtt(xc) ~ -gamma_0*c*(1/((c*u + 1)^2)) - μ*Dt(xc);
reac_diff = Dt(u) ~ D_coef*Dxx(u) - k*u + F_func(x, xc, ro);
eq = [force_eq, reac_diff]

bc = [xc(0)~x0, Dt(xc(0))~0,
     Dt(u(0, t)) ~ 0, Dt(u(L, t))~0];

ERROR: MethodError: no method matching *(::Int64, ::SymbolicUtils.BasicSymbolic{SymbolicUtils.FnType{Tuple, Real}})

Closest candidates are:
  *(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...)
   @ Base operators.jl:578
  *(::T, ::T) where T<:Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8}
   @ Base int.jl:88
  *(::Union{Real, Complex}, ::Union{LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{var"#s972", var"#s9721"}, LinearAlgebra.Transpose{var"#s972", var"#s9721"}} where {var"#s972"<:Union{Real, Complex}, var"#s9721"<:(AbstractVector)}, ::AbstractMatrix{<:Union{Real, Complex}}, ::AbstractMatrix{<:Union{Real, Complex}})
   @ LinearAlgebra C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.9\LinearAlgebra\src\matmul.jl:1218
  ...

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ d:\TwoPhaseProject\twoPhase\FirstFile.jl:18
```